# Setting layer blending as additive with opacity in Kepler GL for Python

Tags: python, layers

I'm using KeplerGL in python (in a Jupyter notebook) to plot polygons on a map with different layers.
After setting the layers, I've tried to find where can I edit their opacity when adding them up, but can't seem to find this option.

Also, tried to look for that in the `map_1.config` but couldn't spot it there either.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from keplergl import KeplerGl 

from keplergl import KeplerGl 
map_1 = KeplerGl(height=500)
map_1.add_data(data=df, name=”data_1”)
```

EDIT: in fact, I found the opacity field in the config json, but it seems like it's not editable.

`map_1.config['config']['visState']['layers'][0]['config']['visConfig']['opacity']`

gives `0.8`. But when I am trying to reassign:

`map_1.config['config']['visState']['layers'][0]['config']['visConfig']['opacity'] = 0.25`

It doesn't change the value and returns 0.8 again.